# How to make CustomScrollView scroll down when keyboard is shown in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to align messages at the bottom of the CustomScrollView (as it is usually done in all chats). This is my code:

```
class TempScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  TempScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TempScreen> createState() => _TempScreenState();
}

class _TempScreenState extends State<TempScreen> {

  List<String> messages = [
    "msg1", "msg2", "msg3", "msg4", "msg5", "msg6", "msg7", "msg8", "msg9", "msg10"
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('AppBar'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Scrollbar(
                child: CustomScrollView(
                  //scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  //shrinkWrap: true,
                  slivers: <Widget>[
                    SliverFillRemaining(
                      hasScrollBody: false,
                      // fillOverscroll: true, // Set true to change overscroll behavior. Purely preference.
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.green,
                              child: SizedBox(height: 1,),
                            ),
                          ),
                          for (var msg in this.messages) ...[
                            Text(msg, style:  TextStyle(fontSize: 30),)
                          ]
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: TextField(
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Message',
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  isDense: true,
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                maxLines: 4,
                minLines: 1,
                //controller: textController,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.send,
                onSubmitted: (value) {
                  this.setState(() {
                    this.messages.add(value);
                  });
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

When application starts first ten messages are shown as expected (aligned at the bottom):

[image]

The problem appears when next messages are added:

[image]

You see, than when keyboard is shown after adding message `11` and and message `12` last messages in `CustomScrollView` are not seen. By other words, when message `12` is added user can't see message `11`. The problem is that CustomScrollView should be scrolled down when keyboard is shown. Could anyone say how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding the reverse property in your custom scroller. it will reverse the scroller's direction.

```
CustomScrollView(
  reverse: true,
  ...
)
```

check this link for more info:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/reverse.html

Answer (score 1):

you can try wrap your widget with padding , and set `viewInsets.bottom`

> When a mobile device's keyboard is visible viewInsets.bottom
> corresponds to the top of the keyboard.

check this documentation for details: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/viewInsets.html

```
body: Padding(
       padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
      .......
```